# How to create list for with_item from included list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this list:

```
"mylist": [
   { "files": [{"path": "path11"}, {"path": "path12"}] },
   { "files": [{"path": "path21"}, {"path": "path22"}] } 
]
```

and I need to run role with *with_items*, where items should be *path* elements from my list.

For example:

```
- debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ mylist | some_magic }}"
```

Needed output:

```
TASK [test : debug] **********************************
ok: [host] => (item=path11 ) => {
    "msg": "path11"
}
ok: [host] => (item=path12 ) => {
    "msg": "path12"
}
ok: [host] => (item=path21 ) => {
    "msg": "path21"
}
...
```

Is it possible?

---

This is what I have already tried:

Constructions look like this:

```
- debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{% for files in mylist | map(attribute='files') %}{% for file in files %}{{file.path}}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}"
```

Returned value as expected is not a list.

Wrong constructions look like this:

```
- debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ mylist | map(attribute='files') | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a legacy [`with_subelements` loop pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements).

Using the `loop` keyword (Ansible 2.5 and later) you can iterate with:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.1.path }}"
  loop: "{{ mylist | subelements('files') }}"
```

Or the same using JMESPath (this shows how to create a list out of the whole data structure):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ mylist | json_query('[].files[].path') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you! Second way is better for me because no flood on the screen.